# XAMPP on MAC - change directory and virtual hosts to other volume

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I am trying to move my default htdocs folder from

> /Applications/xamppfiles/htdocs/

to a folder on another partition at

> /Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/

which happens to be the directory where XAMPP for Windows is installed, allowing me to use the same directory for my website project regardless whether I code on Windows or MAC.
(Note: I am using a Macbook Air with Bootcamp and ParagonNTFS, hence can read/write NTFS partitions)

I have successfully adjusted the httd.conf and vhost.conf files and managed to relocate the localhost directory to point to the files on the other volume, but I do NOT want to change the localhost directory, but rather create a new virtual host that points me to the other volume. So in short, I want these three domains

> localhost -> /Applications/xamppfiles/htdocs/
>
> site1.local -> /Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project1/
>
> site2.local -> /Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project2/

The issue now is that when entering site1.local or site2.local into my browser, the browser redirects me to google because it cannot find the folders.

If I change the forward directory for localhost, things work fine.

> localhost -> /Volumes/Webserver/campp/htdocs/project1/

Following config at play here:

httd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs">

Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Project1
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.local
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project1"
    <Directory "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/site1.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>


# Project2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.local
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project2"
    <Directory "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs/project2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/site2.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>

# localhost [must be included as the default named server]
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Volumes/Webserver/xampp/htdocs">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access the localhost fine, but site1 and site2 dont work. If I change the documentroot of localhost, I can access fine though.

hosts

```
127.0.0.3 site2.local
127.0.0.2 site1.local
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I tried assigning each site its own ip address, but without success.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: doesnt work either way, no matter if I add them all as 127.0.0.1 or give them  individual IPs. The problem is that once I enter  site1.local into the address bar, I end up at google, which points me towards a Vhost issue.

Comment: Ok, get apache to verify the vhost file . change to the xampp apache bin directory and run: `httpd -S`. to find out the options run@ `httpd -help`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to restart about 10 times but now it seems the settings have taken effect. I can confirm the arrangement above works but requires a full restart in order to take effect.